# Rails 3 jQuery Ajax insert record Click

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery, insert

Created new scaffold "Users" that has fields "name" & "description"
All working as suppose to work...

Have another page that has a link that is suppose to insert new record in "Users" when clicked via ajax.

Currently when link is clicked it is inserting record but "name" & "description" fields are not populating...

Here is my jquery code for the link:

```
$("#test-users").click(function(){

    var secure_token = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr("content");

    var dataString = 'authenticity_token='+ secure_token + '&name=' + 'test 1' + '&description=' + 'test 2';  

    $.ajax({  
      type: "POST",  
      url: "http://localhost:3000/users",  
      data: dataString,
      success: function() {  
        alert('success');
      }  
    });

    return false;

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it with `&user[name]=test1&user[description]=test2` for the data (in addition to the token).

Then make sure your controller is accessing the data via `params[:user]`.